# Splitting string using backslash using regex

Tags: python, regex, string, split

For a python program I have an input that I am taking from `stdin` and the input is something like:

```
"-------/--------\---------/------\"
```

When I print it out as a string value it is printed as it is. I am trying to split the string into a list of strings based of forward and backward slash while keeping the separators as well. I have used something like this:

```
re.split('(\\/)',string)
```

but the result that I get is:

```
['------' , '/' , '--------\\\\---------' , '/' , '---------\\\']
```

I was rather expecting it to be something like:

```
['------' , '/' , '---------' , '\' , '---------', '/' , '---------' , '\']
```

What am I doing wrong here and how to solve this problem?

Comment: You made a mistake what you want is not a group of \/ but the characters \ or / so it should be something like : `[\\/]`

Comment: @CladClad I forgot to mention it here but I tried that as well. Something like `re.split('([\\/])',string)` but it didn't work :/ Same results.

Comment: if you want to keep the \ and / you shouldn't use split :)
http://fiddle.re/bnvu9 look at this you can try and see the result :)

Comment: if you put it like `'[\\/]'` it is not possible to keep the separators. However, delimiters can be kept by enclosing them in parentheses like `([\\/])`. I was making the mistake of not taking into account the double escaping because I was not using raw literals

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To capture a delimiter, it's easier to use `findall` instead of `split`:

```
re.findall(r'[^\\/]+|[\\/]', string)
```

`[^\\/]+` would find 1 or more occurrences of sub-strings that do not contain forward or backward slash. `|` works as an or operator. Finally, `[\\/]` will match with the occurrences of forward and backward slash. The result would provide separate sub-strings for the occurrences of forward and backward slash and string matches where they do not occur.

As for why your code didn't work, your expression is `(\\/)`. When Python interpreter parses this, it sees an escaped slash and creates a string of four characters: `( \ / )`. Then, this string is sent to the regex engine, which also does escaping. It sees a slash followed by a backslash, and since backslash is not special, it "escapes" to itself, so the final expression is just `(/)`. Finally, re applies this expression, splits by a backslash and captures it - exactly what you're observing.

The correct command for your approach would be `re.split('([\\\/])',string)` due to double escaping.

The moral of the story: always use raw literals `r"..."` with regexes to avoid double escaping issues.

Comment: Thanks. This works. Any particular reason why my approach is giving me problems?

Comment: @MB_CE: I added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this solution gives exactly what you want:

```
import re
testStr = '-------/--------\\---------/------\\'
parts = re.split('(\\\\|/)', testStr)
for p in parts:
    print('p=' + p)
```

Result:

```
p=-------
p=/
p=--------
p=\
p=---------
p=/
p=------
p=\
p=
```